# I only want apple mobile devices to access a directory, if not a apple mobile device, redirect to another page

Tags: ios, .htaccess, web

so, i have a landing page which i want everyone to be able to access, but in the same page i have a directory that i only want ios devices to be able to reach(example.com/app). i achieved the blocking part with code i found on the net and .htaccess

`SetEnvIf User-Agent "iPhone" allow_ua
    SetEnvIf User-Agent "iPad" allow_ua
    SetEnvIf User-Agent "iPod" allow_ua
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from env=allow_ua`

but this blocks everyone even from example.com

i now want the rest of devices that are not from apple to be redirected to another site(e.g: google.com)

what should i do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a conditional redirect rule using mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !iphone [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://google.com/ [L,R]
```

This will redirect all requestes to google.com if user agent is not iphone

Comment: how can that be used to let ALL iOS devices, not only iphone?